# I need help.. UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc1 in position 0: invalid start byte

Tags: tensorflow, tfrecord

```
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function
from __future__ import absolute_import

import os
import io
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf

from PIL import Image
from object_detection.utils import dataset_util
from collections import namedtuple, OrderedDict

flags = tf.compat.v1.app.flags
flags.DEFINE_string('csv_input', '', 'Path to the CSV input')
flags.DEFINE_string('output_path', '', 'Path to output TFRecord')
flags.DEFINE_string('image_dir', '', 'Path to images')
FLAGS = flags.FLAGS


# replace row_label with the name you annotated your images as
def class_text_to_int(row_label):
    if row_label == 'Masked':
        return 1
    elif row_label == 'No_Masked':
        return 2
    else :
        None


def split(df, group):
    data = namedtuple('data', ['filename', 'object'])
    gb = df.groupby(group)
    return [data(filename, gb.get_group(x)) for filename, x in zip(gb.groups.keys(), gb.groups)]


def create_tf_example(group, path):
    with tf.io.gfile.GFile(os.path.join(path, '{}'.format(group.filename)), 'rb') as fid:
        encoded_jpg = fid.read()
    encoded_jpg_io = io.BytesIO(encoded_jpg)
    image = Image.open(encoded_jpg_io)
    width, height = image.size

    filename = group.filename.encode('utf8')
    image_format = b'jpg'
    xmins = []
    xmaxs = []
    ymins = []
    ymaxs = []
    classes_text = []
    classes = []

    for index, row in group.object.iterrows():
        xmins.append(row['xmin'] / width)
        xmaxs.append(row['xmax'] / width)
        ymins.append(row['ymin'] / height)
        ymaxs.append(row['ymax'] / height)
        classes_text.append(row['class'].encode('utf8'))
        classes.append(class_text_to_int(row['class']))

    tf_example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature={
        'image/height': dataset_util.int64_feature(height),
        'image/width': dataset_util.int64_feature(width),
        'image/filename': dataset_util.bytes_feature(filename),
        'image/source_id': dataset_util.bytes_feature(filename),
        'image/encoded': dataset_util.bytes_feature(encoded_jpg),
        'image/format': dataset_util.bytes_feature(image_format),
        'image/object/bbox/xmin': dataset_util.float_list_feature(xmins),
        'image/object/bbox/xmax': dataset_util.float_list_feature(xmaxs),
        'image/object/bbox/ymin': dataset_util.float_list_feature(ymins),
        'image/object/bbox/ymax': dataset_util.float_list_feature(ymaxs),
        'image/object/class/text': dataset_util.bytes_list_feature(classes_text),
        'image/object/class/label': dataset_util.int64_list_feature(classes),
    }))
    return tf_example


def main(_):
    writer = tf.io.TFRecordWriter(FLAGS.output_path)
    path = os.path.join(FLAGS.image_dir)
    examples = pd.read_csv(FLAGS.csv_input)
    grouped = split(examples, 'filename')
    for group in grouped:
        tf_example = create_tf_example(group, path)
        writer.write(tf_example.SerializeToString())

    writer.close()
    output_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), FLAGS.output_path)
    print('Successfully created the TFRecords: {}'.format(output_path))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    tf.compat.v1.app.run()
```

this is my code named generate_tfrecord.py.
I downloaded this code from github as my first tensorflow tfrecord making example, but it makes error.
I am Korean, and I found that this error occurs when my computer name is korean.
But when I typed 'hostname' in my cmd, it returned 'DESKTOP-7AU~~~', which does not include Korean letters.

If you make comment about your required code or information, I will try to give it to you.

in my images - all folder, there are 764 sets of img+xml file and I have already run "xml_to_csv.py"

this code is from https://github.com/Bengemon825/TF_Object_Detection2020

Comment: Can you include the complete Traceback in your question? The error message itself does not tell in which line the error happens.

Answer (score 0):

this simplest way: you can rename your hostname with ascii characters.
your can search the question that how to rename the hostname by google.

this problem caused by Python read an non-unicode characters and cannot decode by utf-8.

Comment: I actually did it, but it didn't solved problem. My terminal keep giving same error : UnicodeDecodeError. I changed my hostname SuminLaptop, is it right?

Comment: May be you can post your Error traceback in the question description , the we can find what the specific error is

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar problem and here is how I solved it - took me many hours to figure out:

1. If you are a Mac user, MacOS has 'invisible' folder organizing files of the format `.DS_Store` in every folder. When iterating through your images folder, the code runs into these `.DS_Store` files which the utf-8 decoder cannot decode. Deleting them is totally harmless although they in fact do re-appear but you don't have to worry about that
2. So you can get rid of them like [this](https://macpaw.com/how-to/remove-ds-store-files-on-mac)

**OR** (I preferred this option once figured out the problem): In your code, you can explicitly by-pass them with an if statement that checks only for .xml files or .csv files or .txt whichever files you are working with in your images folder/directory. So something like:

`path = 'path to folder containing your .xml files or .csv files or .txt files'`

```
if '.xml' in str(path):
```

3. I have also realized that when people directly use this [generate_tfrecord.py](https://github.com/Bengemon825/TF_Object_Detection2020/blob/master/generate_tfrecord.py) as is, many tend to forget to explicitly call out their file paths correctly. This also happens for people using the [create_pascal_tf_record.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/dataset_tools/create_pascal_tf_record.py) python script of the object_detection api for TensorFlow.

For example, from your code above, `flags.DEFINE_string('csv_input', '', 'Path to the CSV input')`, you need to fill in the ' ' with your csv directory path and not leave it empty. For example `flags.DEFINE_string('csv_input', 'add your csv directory path here', 'Path to the CSV input')`. You have to do the same for all the flags.DEFINE_string instances or else you must explicitly spell out the path if you don't want to use the flags.DEFINE_string instances

I hope this is helpful to anyone using a Mac and running into all sorts of UnicodeDecodeError for TFRECORD files. I'm not sure if Windows users run into something similar. Also there could be other reasons but for me this happened to be the cause